# Ubuntu 12.04 unmet dependency error

Tags: 12.04

I am getting the following unmet dependency issue with Ubuntu 12.04 this happened after the /boot got filled up and had to remove some of the old kernel packages manually.

I have tried various commands below from searching on forums but none of them work, currently I am unable to install any updates or remove any packages.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update

dpkg --force-depends --purge linux*3.2.0.79.93*
apt-get install -f
```

Error message I am getting below is:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.77.91); however:
  Version of linux-image-generic on system is 3.2.0.79.93.
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 3.2.0.77.91); however:
  Version of linux-headers-generic on system is 3.2.0.79.93.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
```

also when I run

```
sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'
```

I get the following output

```
||/ Name                              Version                           Description
+++-=================================-=================================-==================================================================================
un  linux-image                                                   (no description available)
un  linux-image-3.0                                               (no description available)
un  linux-image-3.2.0-60-generic                                  (no description available)
un  linux-image-3.2.0-61-generic                                  (no description available)
rc  linux-image-3.2.0-63-generic      3.2.0-63.95                       Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.2.0-64-generic      3.2.0-64.97                       Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.2.0-65-generic      3.2.0-65.99                       Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic      3.2.0-67.101                      Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-68-generic      3.2.0-68.102                      Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-69-generic      3.2.0-69.103                      Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-70-generic      3.2.0-70.105                      Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-72-generic      3.2.0-72.107                      Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-73-generic      3.2.0-73.108                      Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-74-generic      3.2.0-74.109                      Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-75-generic      3.2.0-75.110                      Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-76-generic      3.2.0-76.111                      Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-77-generic      3.2.0-77.112                      Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-79-generic      3.2.0-79.115                      Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic               3.2.0.79.93                       Generic Linux kernel image
```

Please can anyone help suggest what I can do to fix the problem.

Comment: have you tried sudo dpkg -r linux-generic linux-image-generic and then
sudo apt-get install linux-generic

Comment: That's great.. I will add it as an answer ..

Answer (score 2):

It appears, that the meta-packages `linux-generic`, `linux-image-generic`, `linux-headers-generic` are out of date. You can try

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f
```

to upgrade them and fix issues with unconfigured packages (`-f`).

Alternatively, telling `apt-get` to install `linux-generic` should update just those packages:

```
sudo apt-get install -f linux-generic
```

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Comment: On a side note, this is equivalent to the suggestion in [Aravinda's comment](/questions/605561/ubuntu-12-04-unmet-dependency-error/605567#comment846675_605561), that you say fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The program is asking for linux version 3.2.0.77.91, you don't have this.
You can find .debs below

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/linux-image-server/3.2.0.77.91

Under the Downloadable files header are 2 files, one for 64bit, one for 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

*.79 is the newest version. To do what you want to do you need to do this to all or some of the older versions or you will have dependency issues because linux-image-generic provides the newest version that way you will always get updated kernels in the updates.

Open a terminal and try these commands instead:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic linux-image-3.2.0-68-generic linux-image-3.2.0-69-generic linux-image-3.2.0-70-generic linux-image-3.2.0-71-generic linux-image-3.2.0-72-generic linux-image-3.2.0-73-generic linux-image-3.2.0-74-generic linux-image-3.2.0-75-generic linux-image-3.2.0-76-generic
```